# NEWBIE — Renumbering line numbers in .txt file

Tags: text, sed, grep

I have a simple text file that has been edited so that it looks like this:

```
1,47:26:23N,121:15:10W,1641M,T,3 Queens Mtn,
2,48:01:19N,119:56:12W,367M,T,Alta Lake,
4,48:40:19N,121:35:35W,1705M,T,Anderson Butte,
5,48:36:52N,122:15:58W,736M,T,Anderson Mtn,
6,48:55:13N,120:13:41W,2518M,T,Andrew Peak,
8,47:58:06N,119:55:15W,907M,T,Arbuckle Mtn,
11,48:39:49N,121:31:14W,2138M,T,Bacon Peak,
12,48:46:38N,121:48:48W,3176M,T,Baker Mtn,
13,48:57:12N,120:15:34W,2419M,T,Bald Mtn,
```

I would like to re-edit this file so that it reads:

```
1,47:26:23N,121:15:10W,1641M,T,3 Queens Mtn,
2,48:01:19N,119:56:12W,367M,T,Alta Lake,
3,48:40:19N,121:35:35W,1705M,T,Anderson Butte,
4,48:36:52N,122:15:58W,736M,T,Anderson Mtn,
5,48:55:13N,120:13:41W,2518M,T,Andrew Peak,
6,47:58:06N,119:55:15W,907M,T,Arbuckle Mtn,
7,48:39:49N,121:31:14W,2138M,T,Bacon Peak,
8,48:46:38N,121:48:48W,3176M,T,Baker Mtn,
9,48:57:12N,120:15:34W,2419M,T,Bald Mtn,
```

Any help would be very appreciated (and sorry if this is a really obvious question, but after several attempts I'm not making much progress).

Thanks
Chris

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal, and in what environment? Do want to you use python? bash (or some other shell)? What OS?

Comment: As Tomas said, how do you want to do this? and are there a lot of lines, do you have a rough number?

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear. I'm in OSX and wanted to do this in bash. Have a few thousand lines in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### # solution 1

```
paste -d, <(seq $(wc -l <input.txt)) <(cut -d, -f 2- input.txt)
```

#### # solution 2

```
awk -F, -vOFS=, '{$1=NR}1' input.txt
```

#### # result

```
1,47:26:23N,121:15:10W,1641M,T,3 Queens Mtn,
2,48:01:19N,119:56:12W,367M,T,Alta Lake,
3,48:40:19N,121:35:35W,1705M,T,Anderson Butte,
4,48:36:52N,122:15:58W,736M,T,Anderson Mtn,
5,48:55:13N,120:13:41W,2518M,T,Andrew Peak,
6,47:58:06N,119:55:15W,907M,T,Arbuckle Mtn,
7,48:39:49N,121:31:14W,2138M,T,Bacon Peak,
8,48:46:38N,121:48:48W,3176M,T,Baker Mtn,
9,48:57:12N,120:15:34W,2419M,T,Bald Mtn,
```